# determine standard matrix of a linear map transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm wondering if there is also another easy way of solving question C.
In the book, they use $A = PDP^{-1}$ but the only method I know is by drawing the transformation with vectors $ e_1$ and $e_2$ and then look at the result and  that would be the standard matrix. I tried this method and it did not work for me. I took into account that the vectors only turned so I kept the total length of the vector equal by using unit vectors of the transformation.

[image]

Comment: $E_1$ is the eigenvector. Can you help me more I tried it again but there is something systematic wrong.

Comment: In the future, when you say in your question that “it did not work for me,” please include the details of your work so that someone can show you where you went wrong instead of simply feeding you a solution. Based on your comment to Bernard’s answer, for instance, it appears that the underlying problem here was that you didn’t understand the description of $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the two eigenvectors, the transformation matrix is
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 \\1 & 2\end{pmatrix}.$$
whereas the diagonal matrix would be
$$D=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$
Using these, you can calculate $A$.

If you want to use your approach, you ought to calculate the image of the two basic vectors $e_1,e_2$. One can calculate that using basic geometry, to obtain
$$T(e_1)=T\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0.6 \\ 0.8\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$T(e_2)=T\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0.8 \\ -0.6\end{pmatrix}$$
thus 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0.6 & 0.8 \\ 0.8 & -0.6\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: this is what i tried. i took the unitvector of $[-1 ;2]^T$, this is $[-1/\sqrt{5};  2/\sqrt{5}]^T$. so the vector e_1  $[1; 0]^T$ becomes $[-1/\sqrt{5} ; 2/\sqrt{5}]^T$. but this was wrong. can you explain why this is wrong?

Comment: so basically, my problem is comming to your geometrical endpoints..,

Answer (score 1):

You can do some geometry:

Denote $(x,y)  =T(e_1)$. The line $e_1 T(e_1)$ is orthogonal to the directing vector $(2,1)$, i.e.
$$2(x-1)+1\cdot y=0 $$
Further, $T(e_1)$ has norm $1$, so
$$x^2+y^2=x^2+4(x-1)^2=1\iff 5x^2-8x+3=0.$$
This quadratic equation has two roots: $x=1$, corresponding to vector $e_1$, and $\frac35$, whence $y=\frac45$, corresponding to $T(e_1)$.

Can you do the same for $T(e_2)$ and deduce the matrix $A$?

Comment: i think i did not understand the question correctly. They say:` `" which reflects vecotrs (orthogonally) with respect to the line L "`So i tought that they would be orthogonal to line L. But this is not the case? How can interpreted " orthogonally"?

Comment: For me, $T$ is an orthogonal symmetry w.t.r. line $\ell$.